# Unresolved address to headless service

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, apache-zookeeper, helm3

I have installed `rke2 kube` on a centos8 linux distro, **nodes** are these:

```
NAME                           STATUS   ROLES                       AGE    VERSION
a4b-kube-1.acme.com   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   167m   v1.22.5+rke2r1
a4b-kube-2.acme.com   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   161m   v1.22.5+rke2r1
a4b-kube-3.acme.com   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   158m   v1.22.5+rke2r1
```

So far so good. Problems come when I try to install kafka with helm.

**Values.yaml:**

```
kafka:
  replicaCount: 1
  clusterDomain: acme-kube.local
  zookeeper:
    replicaCount: 3
    clusterDomain: acme-kube.local
    heapOpts: -Xmx128m -Xms128m
  heapOpts: -Xmx256m -Xms256m
```

**requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
- name: kafka
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
  version: 12.18.3
```

**Chart.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
appVersion: "1.0"
description: A Helm chart test for acme
name: acme-test
version: 0.0.1
```

Deploying kafka with these commands after creating the namespace called acme-default:

```
helm dependency update acme-test/
helm --namespace=a4b-test install acme-test acme-test/
```

Pods are these now:

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
acme-test-kafka-0       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (4m46s ago)   18m
acme-test-zookeeper-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (101s ago)    18m
acme-test-zookeeper-1   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (68s ago)     18m
acme-test-zookeeper-2   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (52s ago)     18m
```

Kafka goes in error becasue zookeer is in error, here the kafka's log:

> [2022-01-14 16:41:27,139] ERROR Unable to resolve address:
> acme-test-zookeeper:2181
> (org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider)
> java.net.UnknownHostException: acme-test-zookeeper: Name or
> service not known     at
> java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302)
> at
> org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider$1.getAllByName(StaticHostProvider.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.resolve(StaticHostProvider.java:147)
> at
> org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.next(StaticHostProvider.java:375)
> at
> org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1137)
> [2022-01-14 16:41:27,145] WARN Session 0x0 for server
> acme-test-zookeeper:2181, unexpected error, closing socket
> connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to canonicalize address
> acme-test-zookeeper:2181 because it's not resolvable  at
> org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:71)
> at
> org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:39)
> at
> org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1087)
> at
> org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1139)

While zookeper's log are these:

> 2022-01-14 16:44:27,845 [myid:1] - ERROR
> [ListenerHandler-acme-test-zookeeper-0.acme-test-zookeeper-headless.a4b-default.svc.acme-kube.local:3888:QuorumCnxManager$Listener$ListenerHandler@1094]
>
> - Exception while listening java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address  at
>   java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:388)   at
>   java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:349)   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$Listener$ListenerHandler.createNewServerSocket(QuorumCnxManager.java:1136)
>   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$Listener$ListenerHandler.acceptConnections(QuorumCnxManager.java:1065)
>   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$Listener$ListenerHandler.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:1034)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Same error for the other 2 zookeeper's pods. I dont understand why it cannot resolve, maybe something wrong with kube installation? my **config.yaml** is:

```
server: https://a4b-kube-1.acme.com:9345
token: xxxx
write-kubeconfig-mode: "0644"
tls-san:
  - "acme.com"
cluster-cidr: "10.42.0.0/16"
service-cidr: "10.43.0.0/16"
cluster-dns: "10.43.0.10"
cluster-domain: "acme.com"
```

Comment: Your zookeeper pods are dying so focus on those first, not the Kafka logs... In any case, do you need to use Helm? Why not use an Operator? https://strimzi.io/

Comment: Sure I need to focus and fix zookeeper, than kafka will be ok. Yes I need to use helm

Comment: So, you cannot use Operators at all? Can you share your Zookeeper's values yaml? Btw, I don't think Kafka or Zookeeper will run okay with only `256m` memory

Answer (score 0):

In the zookeeper section you also have to add
clusterDomain: acme-kube.local

Comment: it is there indeed

Comment: Oops, sry, just seen, that clusterDomain was really there